# connecting php codeigniter with android

Tags: json, api

I want to connect with php codeigniter server with my android application. I have tested the code form [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) and able to run the code smoothly. BUt when i try to connect using phpcodeigniter and same json code in android i got some connection error. Here is my logcat

```
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at com.androidhive.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:42)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at com.androidhive.library.UserFunctions.getAllMarkets(UserFunctions.java:34)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at com.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:56)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-28 16:56:03.614: E/AndroidRuntime(1472):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have set apiURL as this : `private static String apiURL = "http://10.0.2.2:81/fol/index.php/api/market_post/";`
here  api is controller and market_post is the method name.

when i run the server code in browser replacing all `$this->input->post()` to `$this->input->get()` and go to the appropriate location in the browser with get value then 
able to see `echo json_encode($response);` .