# How to connect Codeigniter API to an Android App

Tags: php, android, eclipse, codeigniter, api

I have an API built in PHP Codeigniter. I imported it into Eclipse for PHP Developers successfully but I have no Idea how to connect it to my Android App and an existing online PHP database.

I also tried extending it but the core classes in Codeigniter are not available in eclipse's (for PHP) code completion (e.g. on hitting  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>space</kbd> while extending `CI_` classes, options are expected to pop up but they don't).

What can I do to make it work. I tried looking around and found a question here but it has no answers, so I am stuck. Here is the question (in here) that I came across: [connecting php codeigniter with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466151/connecting-php-codeigniter-with-android).

Thanks.

Comment: Can't down voting be done reasonably? What makes this question to be down voted? There are no answers in here that I failed to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to learn Codeigniter from scratch to solve my problem.